# Excel VBA - Search Userform Listbox with Multiple Columns via textbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I'm trying to work out the code needed to filter or search a listbox included on a userform that contains multiple columns and multiple rows. On the userform, I have a textbox that allows user input that would ideally filter out the non-matching entries from the Listbox.

I've found [a few solutions online](http://yoursumbuddy.com/listbox-filter-wildcards-unique-values/), but nothing that I could get to work on a listbox with multiple columns in a userform.  The way it's coded from the example is trying to transpose a single column of data, and I'm guessing I need to alter the code to use an array.  I'm just not strong enough with VBA to know exactly how to change that piece.

I'm also receiving an error on the GoToRow() function, but I believe it's tied into the single vs multiple column listbox issue.

I've included a link to a basic mockup of my project below since I'm using a userform with a listbox and textbox that are named.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/diu05ncwbltepqp/BasicListboxExample.xlsm?dl=0

The listbox on my userform has five columns and is named ProjectList, and the textbox is named SearchTextBox.

```
Option Explicit
Const ProjectNameCol = "B"
Dim PS As Worksheet
Private loActive As Excel.ListObject

Private Sub UserForm_Activate() ' Main code on Userform Activation, calls support subs

    Set PS = Sheets("ProjectSheet") 'stores value for Project Sheet Worksheet as PS
    Set loActive = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

    'populates listbox with data from ProjectSheet Worksheet named table
    ProjectList.RowSource = "AllData"

    '# of Columns for listbox
    ProjectList.ColumnCount = 5

    'Column Width for listbox
    ProjectList.ColumnWidths = "140; 100; 100; 100; 100"

    Me.ProjectList.TextColumn = 1
    Me.ProjectList.MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryComplete
    ResetFilter

End Sub

Private Sub SearchTextBox_Change()
    'Can't get anything to work here
    ResetFilter
End Sub

Sub ResetFilter()

Dim rngTableCol As Excel.Range
Dim varTableCol As Variant
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim FilteredRows() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ArrCount As Long
Dim FilterPattern As String

'the asterisks make it match anywhere within the string
If Not ValidLikePattern(Me.SearchTextBox.Text) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
FilterPattern = "*" & Me.SearchTextBox.Text & "*"

Set rngTableCol = loActive.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
'note that Transpose won't work with > 65536 rows
varTableCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngTableCol.value)
RowCount = UBound(varTableCol)
ReDim FilteredRows(1 To 2, 1 To RowCount)
For i = 1 To RowCount
        'Like operator is case sensitive,
        'so need to use LCase if not CaseSensitive
        If (LCase(varTableCol(i)) Like LCase(FilterPattern)) Then
            'add to array if ListBox item matches filter
            ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
            'there's a hidden ListBox column that stores the record num
            FilteredRows(1, ArrCount) = i
            FilteredRows(2, ArrCount) = varTableCol(i)
        End If
Next i
If ArrCount > 0 Then
    'delete empty array items
    'a ListBox cannot contain more than 65536 items
    ReDim Preserve FilteredRows(1 To 2, 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ArrCount, 65536))
Else
    're-initialize the array
    Erase FilteredRows
End If
If ArrCount > 1 Then
    Me.ProjectList.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FilteredRows)
Else
    Me.ProjectList.Clear
    'have to add separately if just one match
    'or we get two rows, not two columns, in ListBox
    If ArrCount = 1 Then
        Me.ProjectList.AddItem FilteredRows(1, 1)
        Me.ProjectList.List(0, 1) = FilteredRows(2, 1)
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ProjectList_Change()
GoToRow
End Sub

Sub GoToRow()
If Me.ProjectList.ListCount > 0 Then
    Application.Goto loActive.ListRows(Me.ProjectList.value).Range.Cells(1),True
End If
End Sub
```

Over in my modules I have:

```
Function ValidLikePattern(LikePattern As String) As Boolean
Dim temp As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
temp = ("A" Like "*" & LikePattern & "*")
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    ValidLikePattern = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Also, please elaborate why you haven't been able to use the referenced code.

Comment: Thanks Ralph.  I'm definitely in the "aspirant" category.  I've edited my post to include the code I've tried to get working thus far along with the link, but I have yet to get it to actually compile.  Thanks for the feedback.